# How to create a Signed APK on the latest version of Android Studio

Tags: java, android, apk

I just Installed the latest version of Android Studio and I noticed that I can't create a signed APK, it just create a file named `"app-release.apk"` which can't be installed(In the phone).

Comment: If someone answers your questions, it would be nice at least to put a short comment on the answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you have to do :

1. Build **>** Generate Signed APK
2. Deal with the keystore steps.
3. Obtain your signed Apk

In case those steps are new to you, here is a [link that helped me understanding them](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Have a good day !

Comment: I know that, that is what I used to do on the older versions of Android Studio... But I downloaded the latest and it doesn't work that way anymore...

Answer (score 0):

4 months age, when I tried to generate signed apk with android studio `build > Generate Signed APK`, google play said this is not signed apk. So here is my solution if the first one still is not working.

1. Open terminal in your project path
2. ./gradlew --gui

It should open a window for you

1. In `Task Tree` tab, click on arrow key beside your project name, to expand it.
2. then inside there, right click on `assembleRelease`, and select `Execute`.